# Why &x prints a different value every time I run this program?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    int x = 10;
    printf("%d\n",&x);
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `&x` prints out a new value every time I run this program? How do I print `value_of_x` from `location_of_x` in this case and see the output value as `10`?

Comment: Two factors:  (1)   the address of variables of automatic storage duration is not guaranteed, so can change between runs even if conditions appear identical   (2)   Printing an address using `%d` gives undefined behaviour - use `%p` instead.

Comment: _How do I print `*_location_of_x` in this case and see the output as 10?_ This is unclear, please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question "How do I print `*_location_of_x` in this case and see the output as `10`?" See the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // If you use printf, you will need this.
                    // (You could use <cstdio>, but I wouldn't bother.)

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");     // Mixing iostream and stdio output is a bit of
                                   // a code smell.
    int x = 10;
    int *location_of_x = &x;       // No leading _.  Much easier to avoid
                                   // reserved names that way.
    // Use %p to print pointers.  Note that the value printed here is likely to
    // vary from run to run - this makes buffer overflow harder (but not
    // impossible) to exploit
    printf("%p\n",location_of_x);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    // And this is how you indirect through location_of_x
    printf("%d\n",*location_of_x); //
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please introduce indirect through address for a string too?

Comment: @iOS_enthusiast When you say "string", do you mean "array of char", or `std::string`?  `printf` doesn't really like `std::string` - you have to call the `.c_str()` member function.

Comment: I think you really need to get a good book, and read through that.  If you meant "array of char", you can't pass an array of char to `printf` - the array name will decay into a pointer to the characters, so you pass the pointer.

Comment: For both I guess? I was introduced with Java first long ago. This is my second attempt at coding.

Comment: could you suggest one book?

Comment: @iOS_enthusiast • based on your name, I'm going to go out on a limb, and presume you may be interested in programming for iOS.  If that is the case, I recommend the book [iOS Programming](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0134682335), which uses Swift.

Answer (score 6):

The location in memory where your local variable is stored changes from execution to execution. You should use %p (normally used for pointers) instead %d (used for integers) to display the address of x, however that doesn't change the fact that the address will be different every time you start the program.
If i remember correctly the randomization is done through [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) and is done in order to prevent certain kinds of exploits.

Comment: Support of ASLR is not universal.   It is a build option for linux, for example, which is most commonly enabled in hardened distributions.